# react-highcharts how to call reflow?

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I use [kirjs/react-highcharts](https://github.com/kirjs/react-highcharts) plugin for react but I have no idea how to get Highchart component in order to call `reflow` like: `$('#container1').highcharts().reflow()`

From docs its tells:

> For access to methods & properties from the Highcharts library you can use ReactHighcharts.Highcharts. For example, the Highcharts options are available via ReactHighcharts.Highcharts.getOptions().

but I don't see there any `reflow()` method.

Any ideas?

**Edit**

its located under `ReactHighcharts.Highcharts.charts` so I can call

```
ReactHighcharts.Highcharts.charts[0].reflow()
```

but it has list of all highchart instances so I have no information what index is mine

Comment: You could use Highcharts with React without that plugin as shown in this official Highcharts article: http://www.highcharts.com/blog/192-use-highcharts-to-create-charts-in-react For the plugin you are using - text in documentation, right after the one you posted is about `chart.series[0].addPoint(...` and `chart.reflow()` should be used in a similar way.

Answer (score 2):

I am using highcharts-react-official and highcharts. They are available via [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-react-official) . Although I am using different packages, the working principle should be the same.

The way of using reflow() function in react-highchart is also Highcharts.charts[i].reflow(). I have prepared 2 code sandboxes for the demonstration. The first code sandbox shows the way of re-flowing every chart, and the second code sandbox shows the way of re-flowing a particular chart.

The first code sandbox link is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-highcharts-reflow-example-5srh9?file=/src/App.js:851-881).

1. There is a button on App.js to hide and show highchart divs.
2. The child component is React.memo (for performance optimization), therefore the hidden highchart will not be auto resized after it becomes visible.
3. To let every chart window resize with respect to the window size. The following code is placed in App.js. It looks for all existing charts and re-flow them:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < Highcharts.charts.length; i++) {
      if (Highcharts.charts[i] !== undefined) {
        Highcharts.charts[i].reflow();
      }
    }
```

The second code sandbox link is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-highchart-reflow-for-particular-chart-9f7ly?file=/src/HighChartsReflow.js).

1. Almost the same as the first code sandbox, but there is a ref array of referencing every chart.
2. The chart which needs re-flowing is placed with an id in its chart option.
3. Iterate every chart and get the index of the chart with that id e.g. "secondChart" for this example.

```
    for (var i = 0; i < chartRef.current.length; i++) {
      if (
        chartRef.current[i].chart.userOptions.id !== undefined &&
        chartRef.current[i].chart.userOptions.id === "secondChart"
      )
        Highcharts.charts[chartRef.current[i].chart.index].reflow();
    }
```

4. Re-flow that chart.

Answer (score 2):

The Reflow can be set with event `load` in options.

Workaround: You have to set `reflow()` using `setTimeout()` this will trigger the resizing. Time is set to 0 to avoid delay.

**Solution**

```
const options = {
    chart: {
      type: 'column',
      style: {},
      events: {
        load() {
          setTimeout(this.reflow.bind(this), 0);
        },
      },
    },
    title: 'Column Chart',
  }
```

**Usage**

```
<HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={options} />
```